# Subtracting two points, the math.

Tags: geometry

I would like to confirm the math of subtracting two points. I've looked online but all of the sources I have seen want to end up with a vector, I need to end with a point.

I am looking at this function in [this link](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/raysphere.c),

```
/*
   Calculate the intersection of a ray and a sphere
   The line segment is defined from p1 to p2
   The sphere is of radius r and centered at sc
   There are potentially two points of intersection given by
   p = p1 + mu1 (p2 - p1)
   p = p1 + mu2 (p2 - p1)
   Return FALSE if the ray doesn't intersect the sphere.
*/
int RaySphere(XYZ p1,XYZ p2,XYZ sc,double r,double *mu1,double *mu2)
{
   double a,b,c;
   double bb4ac;
   XYZ dp;

   dp.x = p2.x - p1.x;
   dp.y = p2.y - p1.y;
   dp.z = p2.z - p1.z;
   a = dp.x * dp.x + dp.y * dp.y + dp.z * dp.z;
   b = 2 * (dp.x * (p1.x - sc.x) + dp.y * (p1.y - sc.y) + dp.z * (p1.z - sc.z));
   c = sc.x * sc.x + sc.y * sc.y + sc.z * sc.z;
   c += p1.x * p1.x + p1.y * p1.y + p1.z * p1.z;
   c -= 2 * (sc.x * p1.x + sc.y * p1.y + sc.z * p1.z);
   c -= r * r;
   bb4ac = b * b - 4 * a * c;
   if (ABS(a) < EPS || bb4ac < 0) {
      *mu1 = 0;
      *mu2 = 0;
      return(FALSE);
   }

   *mu1 = (-b + sqrt(bb4ac)) / (2 * a);
   *mu2 = (-b - sqrt(bb4ac)) / (2 * a);

   return(TRUE);
}
```

specifically at the comments at the top of the function.

I have programmatically found my `mu` and now need to apply them to the points. So to make sure subtracting $(x_1, y_1)$ from $(x_2, y_2)$ would go
$$(x_1-x_2,\quad y_1-y_2)$$
Then applying `mu` to a point would just be

$$(x\cdot\mu,\quad y\cdot\mu)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "subtraction" of two points does produce a vector in the way you are describing. The idea is that this subtraction gives you the displacement vector between the two points. So if we have $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ then the operation: $$P-Q = (x_1 - x_2, y_1- y_2)$$ is the vector that when you add it to the point $Q$ it will get you to the point $P$.

In this context the operations you are expecting hold true. That is the operation of vector addition and subtraction as well as scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, points - given by their coordinates in 3-space - are identified with vectors, thus justifying the calculations made.